# How to get returned a list/dictionary of objects based on Max value with Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, max

`Model.objects.filter(pid=12345).aggregate(Max('width'))` - will get a list of pictures, with pid 12345 , then pick picture with the greatest width and return a dictionary {'width':512}.

But i need an object to get returned , so the question is ...

**Question:** How to get returned a list/dictionary of objects based on Max values.

Comment: You are _calculating_ the Sum, Max, Avg, etc., on the result of a filter that returns multiple objects. I'm not sure you would get an object from a function that breaks down objects. Can you be more specific about the final result you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obj = Model.objects.filter(pid=12345).order_by('-width')[0]

result = {'width': obj.width}

Comment: yeah , after writing this question i figured i could do order_by and take the first object , which will be with the biggest width, it's just i thought there could be a better solution to this problem.